# JPA query with SELECT CASE WHEN

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Have a query like this,

```
select *
from job_profile
where case
    when exists (
        select 1
        from job_profile
        where screening_type_id = 2 and job_category_id = 4 
        )
    then screening_type_id = 2 and job_category_id = 4 
    else screening_type_id =4
    end;
```

which I need to write this in JPA.

```
String GET_JOB_VACCINATIONS_BY_JOB_CAT_ID_AND_SCRN_TYPE_ID = "SELECT jobvacc FROM JobVaccination jobvacc WHERE  CASE"
            + " WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT 1 FROM  JobVaccination jobvacc2 WHERE  jobvacc2.jobCategoryMast.jobCategoryId=:jobCategoryId AND jobvacc2.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId=:screeningTypeId )"
            + " THEN  jobvacc.jobCategoryMast.jobCategoryId=4 AND jobvacc.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId=2 "
            + " ELSE jobvacc.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId=2"
            + " END";
```

Tried this way which throws exception like "**Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: = near line 1, column 260 [SELECT............."**

Cant we write the case queries in JPA ?

Refereed this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#New_in_JPA_2.0 which says yes.

Comment: Seems the problem is when try to replace the parameters in your query, could do you try an example without parameters to check if the case keyworkd works fine?

Comment: Tried this way  ** String GET_JOB_VACCINATIONS_BY_JOB_CAT_ID_AND_SCRN_TYPE_ID = "SELECT jobvacc FROM JobVaccination jobvacc WHERE  CASE"
   + " WHEN EXISTS (  SELECT 1 FROM  JobVaccination jobvacc2 WHERE  jobvacc2.jobCategoryMast.jobCategoryId=4 AND jobvacc2.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId=4 )"
   + " THEN  jobvacc.jobCategoryMast.jobCategoryId = 4 AND jobvacc.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId = 2 "
        + " ELSE jobvacc.screeningTypeMast.screeningTypeId = 2"
   + " END";**  - same exception

Comment: I don't think `then screening_type_id = 2 and job_category_id = 4 else screening_type_id =4` is a legal SQL query fragment. Infact CASE should be used in SELECT clause not WHERE clause. What are you trying to do by that fragment?

Comment: The query statement is working perfectly fine. Tried in PostgreSQL.

Comment: If this screening_type_id = 2 and job_category_id = 4  returns empty then  fetch data  screening_type_id =4.